# How does one go about making a function which replaces a specific index

Tags: python, python-3.x

i don't think I've fully grasped the concept of a function so it is inhibiting my ability to further myself.
I have this challenge that i can't quite figure out, here it is. I'm unclear how to set a function up to do the thing i want it to do because the parameters in the parentheses are throwing me off. I'd prefer it if you could kindly show me the way instead of fixing the code. Thank you very much for taking the time to read and/or reply.

```
Function Challenge: create replacement function¶

    Create a function, str_replace, that takes 2 arguments: int_list and index
        int_list is a list of single digit integers
        index is the index that will be checked - such as with int_list[index]
    Function replicates purpose of task "replace items in a list" above and replaces an integer with a string "small" or "large"
    return int_list
```

---

```
int_list = [3, 6, 9]
index = int_list[0]
def str_replace(int_list, index=""):
    if int_list[0] < 5:
        index = 'small'
    else:
        index = 'large'
    print(index)
    return str_replace(int_list)
```

Comment: Whats the show desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
int_list = [3, 6, 9]
def str_replace(int_list, index):
    if int_list[index] < 5:
        int_list[index] = 'small'
    else:
        int_list[index] = 'large'
    return int_list
str_replace(int_list, 0)
# Out[14]: ['small', 6, 9]
int_list = [3, 6, 9]
str_replace(int_list, 1)
# Out[17]: [3, 'large', 9]
int_list = [3, 6, 9]
str_replace(int_list, 2)
# Out[18]: [3, 6, 'large']
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

```
int_list = [1,2,3,4,5]  # list created def str_replace(int_list, index): # index is a static position you will type in.
    if int_list[index] < 5:
        int_list[index] = "small"
    else:
        int_list[index] = "large"
    print "Your index is: ", index 
    print int_list[:]



str_replace(int_list,1)
```